# a regular graph has 15 edges, how many vertices does it have?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to compute $|V|$ for a regular graph with 15 edges. According to this lemma:

$\sum_{v \in V} deg(v)=2|E|$

Whatever $|V|$ is, it should satisfy the above lemma. Based on that fact that in a regular graph, all vertices have the same degree, and that $|V|$ is an integer:

$\sum k = 2*15=30$

The only way for it to be correct is that $k=2,3,5$, which results in $|V|=6,10,15$. For example, if all vertices have a degree of $5$, then:

$\sum 5 = 30$

$5 |V| = 30$

So,

$|V|=\frac{30}{5}=6$

This was my solution, but I saw another solution which looks a little odd to me. It is based on the assumption that:

> In a regular graph, $deg(v)=|V|-1$.

which I think is not true. But anyway, this solution uses the above assumption to obtain:

$\sum (|V|-1)=30 \Rightarrow |V| ( |V| -1) =30$

$|V|^2 - |V| =30$

$(|V|-6)\cdot(|V|+5)=0$

Then it accepts $|V|=6$, because, the number of vertices can't be a negative number.

Now my question is: is that assumption "in a regular graph, $deg(v)=|V|-1$" correct? Which answer is correct?

Comment: This is true for a complete graph.

Comment: A square is regular and each vertex has degree 2 but has 4 vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that in a regular graph, the degree is $|V| - 1$. The degree can be 1 (a bunch of isolated edges) or 2 (any cycle) etc. In a *complete* graph, the degree of each vertex is $|V| - 1$.

Your argument is correct, assuming you are dealing with connected simple graphs (no multiple edges.) If they need not be connected, you miss the case $k=1$ with 30 vertices.

Answer (score -1):

Number of edges $=|E|=15$
Number of vertices$=|V|=n=?$
$$
\begin{split}
|E|&=n\cdot\frac{k}{26} \\
2\cdot|E|&=n\cdot k\\
2\cdot 15&=n\cdot k\\
n&=\frac{30}{k}
\end{split}
\qquad\text{ where }k=2,3,5,\ldots
$$
At $k=1$ graph will be disconnected.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).